# Django 1.9 - Not displaying user uploaded images

Tags: django, django-1.9

I am trying to display images that have been uploaded by the user, but no matter what I try I am getting the broken link icon. I have searched and searched through the documentation, on SO and elsewhere for a couple of days now to no avail. I am new to Django and currently in development so I'm sure I've made some other rookie mistakes, but right now the only thing I care about is displaying uploaded images in templates.

Here are the relevant snippets of my code:

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/media_root/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media", "media_root")
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/?', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
    url(r'^about/?', profiles.views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^properties/single/?', properties.views.single, name='single_mens'),
    url(r'^properties/married/?', properties.views.married, name='married'),
    url(r'^properties/add/add_photos/?', properties.views.add_photos, name='add_photos'),
    url(r'^properties/add/?', properties.views.add_rental, name='add_rental'),
    url(r'^', profiles.views.home, name='home'),
] 

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

**models.py**

```
class RentalPicModel(models.Model):

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.image.url

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="pics/originals/", null=True)
    rental = models.ForeignKey(RentalModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**forms.py**

```
class AddPhotosForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = RentalPicModel
        fields = ['image', 'rental']

    def clean_image(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['image']

    def clean_rental(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['rental']
```

**views.py**

```
def add_photos(request):

    form = AddPhotosForm
    current_rental = None
    current_photos = []
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddPhotosForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if request.POST.get('another'):
            if form.is_valid():
                cleaned_image = form.cleaned_data['image']
                cleaned_rental = form.cleaned_data['rental']
                current_rental = cleaned_rental

                pic = RentalPicModel(image=cleaned_image, rental=cleaned_rental)
                pic.save()

        current_photos = RentalPicModel.objects.filter(rental=current_rental)
        current_photos = [rental.image for rental in current_photos]
        for photo in current_photos:
            print photo

    context = {
        'form' : form,
        'photos' : current_photos,
    }

    return render(request, "add_photos.html", context)
```

Here the output of the `print` statement (after uploading one photo) is: `pics/originals/DSC_1376.jpg` and I can see the file is saved to that location.

**add_photos.html**

```
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Upload your photos here.</h1>
        <br>
        <div class='row'>
            <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy }}
                <div class='col col-xs-3'></div>
                <div class='col col-xs-3'>
                    <input class="btn btn-block btn-info" name="another" type="submit" value="Save and Add Another">
                </div>
                <div class='col col-xs-3'>
                    <input class="btn btn-block btn-primary" name="finish" type="submit" value="Save and Finish">
                </div>
                <div class="col col-xs-3"></div>
            </form>
        </div>

        {% if photos|length > 0 %}
            <h2>Uploaded photos:</h2>
            {% for photo in photos %}
                <div class='row'>
                    <img src="{{ photo.url }}" alt="">
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
```

When I inspect the `<img>` element, I see `src="/media/media_root/pics/originals/DSC_1376.jpg"` which gives me a url of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/media_root/pics/originals/DSC_1376.jpg`. This seems to be the correct file location to me, but it is still not displaying.

Like I say, everything seems to me to be set up how it is described in the Django documentation and in every other question I've read on SO.  What am I missing?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Do I need to modify my `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting at all for uploaded media?  Here is what I have right now:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_files"),
)
```

which is where I've put all my CSS and javascript files.

Comment: Do you get a 404 for the file or is it "no displaying" as in "broken". Maybe a 0 kB file?

Comment: @C14L It just displays the broken image icon.  I've checked the file and it's there and certainly larger than 0 kB.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to concatenate the `MEDIA_URL` and the `{{ photo.url }}`.

**Try:**

```
<img src="{% get_media_prefix %}{{ photo.url }}" alt="">
```

More about `{% get_media_prefix %}` [HERE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#get-media-prefix) in the docs.

Comment: Still not displaying.  The only thing I can think of is that I have placed my media directory in the wrong place?  If all my code is inside a `src` folder (and, for example, `manage.py` is right inside that directory) can my `media` folder be outside the `src` folder?  I tried putting it inside as well with no change, though, so I guess that may not be the issue.

Comment: If you can't see any image on URL: .../media/media_root/... then the problem is in the configuration (settings) or if you haven't any image in that directory then something in the views or add_photos.html is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

My urls were the problem.  When it was trying to retrieve the media files, it matched `url(r'^', profiles.views.home, name='home')` before it matched any of the media urls.  A simple `$` fixed it:

```
url(r'^$', profiles.views.home, name='home')
```